# IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied when trying to open hidden file in "w" mode

Tags: python, windows, winapi, file-io, hidden-files

I want to replace the contents of a hidden file, so I attempted to open it in `w` mode so it would be erased/truncated:

```
>>> import os
>>> ini_path = '.picasa.ini'
>>> os.path.exists(ini_path)
True
>>> os.access(ini_path, os.W_OK)
True
>>> ini_handle = open(ini_path, 'w')
```

But this resulted in a traceback:

```
IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '.picasa.ini'
```

However, I was able to achieve the intended result with `r+` mode:

```
>>> ini_handle = open(ini_path, 'r+')
>>> ini_handle.truncate()
>>> ini_handle.write(ini_new)
>>> ini_handle.close()
```

**Q.** What is the difference between the `w` and `r+` modes, such that one has "permission denied" but the other works fine?

**UPDATE:** I am on win7 x64 using Python 2.6.6, and the target file has its hidden attribute set. When I tried turning off the hidden attribute, `w` mode succeeds. But when I turn it back on, it fails again.

**Q.** Why does `w` mode fail on hidden files? Is this known behaviour?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

It's just how the Win32 API works.  Under the hood, Python's `open` function is calling the [`CreateFile`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363858%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function, and if that fails, it translates the Windows error code into a Python `IOError`.

The `r+` open mode corresponds to a `dwAccessMode` of `GENERIC_READ|GENERIC_WRITE` and a `dwCreationDisposition` of `OPEN_EXISTING`.   The `w` open mode corresponds to a `dwAccessMode` of `GENERIC_WRITE` and a `dwCreationDisposition` of `CREATE_ALWAYS`.

If you carefully read the remarks in the `CreateFile` documentation, it says this:

> If `CREATE_ALWAYS` and `FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL` are specified, `CreateFile` fails and sets the last error to `ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED` if the file exists and has the `FILE_ATTRIBUTE_HIDDEN` or `FILE_ATTRIBUTE_SYSTEM` attribute. To avoid the error, specify the same attributes as the existing file.

So if you were calling `CreateFile` directly from C code, the solution would be to add in `FILE_ATTRIBUTE_HIDDEN` to the `dwFlagsAndAttributes` parameter (instead of just `FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL`).  However, since there's no option in the Python API to tell it to pass in that flag, you'll just have to work around it by either using a different open mode or making the file non-hidden.

Comment: +1 for linking Win32 API docs. Your explanation is exactly what I was looking for. By myself, I only got as far as the [implementation](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/c6880edaf6f3/Objects/fileobject.c#l318) of Python's `open` function.

Comment: @MrGamgee: Yeah, Python calls the `_wfopen` function, which is part of the Microsoft C runtime library (CRT).  If you have Visual Studio installed, you can look at the CRT source, typically in somewhere like `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\crt\src`.  The implementation of `_wfopen` eventually calls `CreateFile` (after a few intermediate function calls).

Comment: @Adam, how do you trace what underlying C function gets called?

Comment: I cannot believe this isn't more remarked upon. THANKS GOOGLE! Just busted my ass for over an hour assuming something was up with the file permissions because I couldn't amend or write to a hidden file. In all my years of coding I'd never come across this. This seems to be the only place according to google where people are discussing this behaviour.

Answer (score 5):

Here are the detailed differences:-

> ``r''   Open text file for reading.  The stream is positioned at the
>            beginning of the file.
>
> ``r+''  Open for reading and writing.  The stream is positioned at
>   the
>            beginning of the file.
>
> ``w''   Truncate file to zero length or create text file for writing.
>            The stream is positioned at the beginning of the file.
>
> ``w+''  Open for reading and writing.  The file is created if it does
>   not
>            exist, otherwise it is truncated.  The stream is positioned at
>            the beginning of the file.
>
> ``a''   Open for writing.  The file is created if it does not exist. 
>   The
>            stream is positioned at the end of the file.  Subsequent writes
>            to the file will always end up at the then current end of file,
>            irrespective of any intervening fseek(3) or similar.
>
> ``a+''  Open for reading and writing.  The file is created if it does
>   not
>            exist.  The stream is positioned at the end of the file.  Subse-
>            quent writes to the file will always end up at the then current
>            end of file, irrespective of any intervening fseek(3) or similar.

From python documentation - http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files:-

> On Windows, 'b' appended to the mode opens the file in binary mode, so
>   there are also modes like 'rb', 'wb', and 'r+b'. Python on Windows
>   makes a distinction between text and binary files; the end-of-line
>   characters in text files are automatically altered slightly when data
>   is read or written. This behind-the-scenes modification to file data
>   is fine for ASCII text files, but it’ll corrupt binary data like that
>   in JPEG or EXE files. Be very careful to use binary mode when reading
>   and writing such files. On Unix, it doesn’t hurt to append a 'b' to
>   the mode, so you can use it platform-independently for all binary
>   files.

So if you are using `w` mode, you are actually trying to create a file and you may not have the permissions to do it. `r+` is the appropriate choice.

If you are in a situation where you do not yet know where your `.picasi.ini` exists or not and your windows user has file creation permissions in that directory and you want to append new information instead of starting at the beginning of the file (a.k.a "append"), then `a+` will be the appropriate choice.

It has nothing to do with whether your file is hidden or not.

Comment: -1 for copying and pasting from Python docs and not reading the question. I used `r+` mode which allows updating, ie both reading and writing.

Comment: You say "`w` Truncate file to zero length or create text file for writing". But then you say later "if you are using `w` mode, you are actually trying to create a file" Which is it?

Comment: If it doesn't exist, it creates the file. If it exists, it truncates the file to zero length so anything you write on it begins from the start of the file.

Comment: You seem to be missing my point. The reason I checked whether the file exists and whether I have write permissions was merely to rule out possible sources of the IOError for those reading the question, not because I don't know whether the file exists!

Comment: "It has nothing to do with whether your file is hidden or not." Please consider this fact: (1) Set hidden attribute. (2) `w` mode fails. (3) Unset hidden attribute (4) `w` mode succeeds. This is repeatable. I have just checked with `ini` and `jpg` files.

Comment: This answer is confidently wrong, I wish you would just delete it.

Answer (score 3):

Thanks for this thread; I had the same issue today. My workaround is as follows. Works with Python 3.7

```
import os

GuiPanelDefaultsFileName = 'panelDefaults.json'
GuiPanelValues = {
    '-FileName-'      : os.getcwd() + '\\_AcMovement.xlsx',
    '-DraftEmail-'    : True,
    '-MonthComboBox-' : 'Jun',
    '-YearComboBox-'  : '2020'
}

# Unhide the file via OS
if os.path.isfile(GuiPanelDefaultsFileName):
    os.system(f'attrib -h {GuiPanelDefaultsFileName}')

# Write dict values to json
with open(GuiPanelDefaultsFileName, 'w') as fp:
    json.dump(GuiPanelValues, fp, indent=4)

# Make it hidden again
os.system(f'attrib +h {GuiPanelDefaultsFileName}')
```