# Is it possible to write to a hidden file in Java?

Tags: java, file, io, hidden-files

I have figured out how to create a hidden file in Java, now I need to write large amounts of data to the file. I keep getting the following exception:`SEVERE: java.io.FileNotFoundException: <filepath>\tmp (Access is denied)`

Here are two approaches I took to get try and get a solution, but I get the same exception for both approaches. Note: toOverwrite is the hidden file in both cases.

```
File fileByteText = new File("./testFile.txt");
File toOverwrite = new File("./tmp");
//Assume toOverwrite is hidden

boolean toReturn = true;
    try {
        byte[] fileByteText = FileUtils.readFileToByteArray(toGetTextFrom);
                    FileUtils.writeByteArrayToFile(toOverwrite, fileByteText,    false);
                    toReturn = false;
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    bam.severe(e);
                    toReturn = true;
                }
```

Approach two using the same file objects:

```
try {
                String fileText = FileUtils.readFileToString(toGetTextFrom);
                FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(toOverwrite.getAbsoluteFile());
                BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
                bw.write(fileText);
                bw.close();
                toReturn = false;
            } catch (IOException e1) {
                bam.severe(e1);
                toReturn = true;
            }
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13215716/ioerror-errno-13-permission-denied-when-trying-to-open-hidden-file-in-w-mod

Answer (score 0):

You can get an Exception when you try to write to a file of type directory.
Check what method toOverWrite.isFile() returns;

if false you cannot write.

Comment: What? Lol I'm assuming you are saying that I cannot write to a directory. I am not writing to a directory, it is a file. I added an extension to the filename, it still doesn't work.

Comment: So isFile() returns true?, Then check what file.canWrite() returns

Comment: Yes, isFile() returns true, canWrite() also returns true.

Comment: Then attach the jdk source to your projekt and debug into, then you see where, and hopefully why the exception is raised.

Answer (score -1):

There is no magic in Unix. Just prepend a `.` to your filename. Under Windows, this cannot be achieved with Java. You need native commands. May this works with NIO2.

Comment: Yes, I know how to create a hidden file in unix and windows. I am more concerned with writing to the file once it is hidden.