# open() is not working for hidden files python

Tags: python

I want to create and write a .txt file in a hidden folder using python. I am using this code:

```
file_name="hi.txt"
temp_path = '~/.myfolder/docs/' + file_name
file = open(temp_path, 'w')
file.write('editing the file')
file.close()
print 'Execution completed.'
```

where ~/.myfolder/docs/ is a hidden folder. I ma getting the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 3, in <module>
    file = open(temp_path, 'w')
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '~/.myfolder/docs/hi.txt'
```

The same code works when I save the file in some non-hidden folder.

Any ideas why open() is not working for hidden folders.

Comment: What OS are you using?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13215716/ioerror-errno-13-permission-denied-when-trying-to-open-hidden-file-in-w-mod

Comment: No it does work for hidden files

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The problem isn't that it's hidden, it's that Python cannot resolve your use of `~` representing your home directory. Use [`os.path.expanduser`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.expanduser),

```
>>> with open('~/.FDSA', 'w') as f:
...     f.write('hi')
... 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '~/.FDSA'
>>> 
>>> import os
>>> with open(os.path.expanduser('~/.FDSA'), 'w') as f:
...     f.write('hi')
... 
>>>
```