# File is not uploading in flask

Tags: python, python-3.x, file, flask, file-upload

I'm learning python (Flask)
I've tried to upload file by flask but it show an error

**> PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'C:\Users\Muhammad Usama Javed\Desktop\autotech\static\upload_files'**

Here's my code

```
@app.route('/upload_files', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def upload_files():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if request.files:
            # fn.fun_upload_files(request.files['img'])
            img = request.files['img']
            filename = img.filename
            img.save(os.path.join("C:\\Users\\Muhammad Usama Javed\\Desktop\\autotech\\static\\upload_files"), filename)
    return redirect('/admin/files')
```

[The error you can see in picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fqjq8.png)

Comment: Check that the location is set up [with the correct permissions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41910583/errno-13-permission-denied-python).

Comment: try using relative paths

Answer (score 0):

You may not have configured the application. Try adding this value:

```
import os
from flask import Flask, flash, request, redirect, url_for
from werkzeug.utils import secure_filename

# The path where the files will be saved
UPLOAD_FOLDER = '/path/to/the/uploads'

ALLOWED_EXTENSIONS = {'txt', 'pdf', 'png', 'jpg', 'jpeg', 'gif'}

app = Flask(__name__)

# Add a new value in the config application
app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'] = UPLOAD_FOLDER
```

[Source](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/patterns/fileuploads/)