# Python permission error when loading dataset

Tags: python, error-handling, neural-network, dataset, pickle

I am currently working on loading in a dataset that I have downloaded for training with a neural network, yet I get the following error. I have already tried killing all python.exe processes and restarting VSCode, I have checked all administrator permissions for the folder/files, and I have tried using chown and chmod to fix permissions as well. Picture 1 has the bulk of the code, picture 2 has the method for Model.load().

[Error Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qKnRL.png)

[Method](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y8bQT.png)

Comment: You have a file permission issue. Read :
[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41910583/errno-13-permission-denied-python)

Comment: I think that is a bit obvious... I've already looked at that thread and it has not been very helpful.

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow!  Instead of linking, would you mind editing your post and typing out the error code et al?