# Sliced images not written to output directory

Tags: python, image, split

I am slicing an image using Python's split_image package.

```
from split_image import split_image
img = "path\to\input\image"
split_image(img, 4, 2, False, False, open("\path\to\output\images", "w"))
```

Essentially, the above code should read the input image, split it into 8 parts and write the set of sliced images to a folder. However, I get the following error:

```
[Errno 13] Permission denied: "\path\to\output\images".
```

Is there a workaround for this problem?

Comment: Well, do you have write permissions to that directory? Whta happens when you use forward slashes: `open("/path/to/output/images/", "w")`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Errno 13 Permission denied Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41910583/errno-13-permission-denied-python)

Comment: I do have permission for that directory.

Comment: Is the path correct? Your input dir starts without a leading backslash while your output has a leading backslash?