# Python | PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied:

Tags: python, permissionerror

I am currently learning Python using Al Sweigart's book. I have an issue with the open function when passing 'w' as an argument: it is supposed to create a file if the the filename I passed doesn't exist but it doesn't and instead it shows the error message in the image (this is an example from the book)

```
baconFile = open('bacon.txt', 'w')
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<pyshell#2>", line 1, in <module>
baconFile = open('bacon.txt', 'w')
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'bacon.txt'
```

Tha same error gets displayed when I use shelve.open from the shelve open.

Thank you for any explanation/solution.

I tried openeing other files with 'w' as an argument and it works only if the file exists already but if I try to open a non-existing one, it doesn't create it like it's supposed to and it just displays the same error.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I added an image with the code but it doesn't show so here it is:                    
 baconFile = open('bacon.txt', 'w')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#2>", line 1, in <module>
    baconFile = open('bacon.txt', 'w')
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'bacon.txt'

Comment: [Do not upload images of code](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors/285557#285557). Edit your post and paste the code into the original post formatted as a code block.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Errno 13 Permission denied](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41910583/errno-13-permission-denied)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The file `bacon.txt` is owned by a different user account.

You are running the program as a user that does not have permission to overwrite it.

Comment: Thank you. I think this is the issue. I ll try to look into how to run with "upgraded" permissions.